# didReceiveMemoryWarning: what type of memory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiwebview

I have a base cordova app, with some objective-c code around cordova's framework. Sometimes I've `didReceiveMemoryWarning` notification, but I don't understand if the problem is the javascript inside the UIWebView or other.
The documentation says:

> Your app never calls this method directly. Instead, this method is called when the system determines that the amount of available memory is low.

But my question is: what type of memory? 
RAM? Heap allocations? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RAM, it is for RAM, if your app consuming more memory without realising it, and no memory to remain to process any more thread then, this didreceivememorywarning get called by system.

Comment: This appens using the content of webview, so I can't release objects. I've a lot of javascript code, there is a way to release memory of webview without realese it?

Comment: Well in that case every bit of data getting stored in your RAM. And continues browsing make your app heavier and this method must called, without seeing any code structure i can't help you more here.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should profile your app with Instruments and you'll get a better picture of what's consuming memory.

Answer (score 1):

The memory issue represents to RAM, generally we are creating the app using different objects, and these objects take some memory to process the required task. If we aware about them we can easily manage the memory but sometimes  for beginners it is not managable to debug the memory, and `didReceiveMemoryWarning` occured. We can diagnose or debug this issue by instruments.